# vba excel: How to fill in two cells in a row with text

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make a header in my excel sheet using VBA. Seems pretty simple, but when I do this

```
Worksheets("New_Students").Range("A1").Value = "studentID"
Worksheets("New_Students").Range("B1").Value = "ISUID"
```

only the first line works and not the second one. What am I forgetting?

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: can you give an example of "the second one doesn't work"?  Is it not populating at all, giving an error, giving a different result, etc.  From what you posted, there's no reason why it wouldn't work.  There may be something else going on somewhere else in your code that's causing B1 to not be what you want it to be.  You'll need to either provide the full macro or provide more context to get a usable answer...

Comment: Thank you for your replies!
Second line doesn't do anything, just leaves B1 empty. However, if I switch the order of the lines in the macro

`Worksheets("New_Students").Range("B1").Value = "ISUID"
Worksheets("New_Students").Range("A1").Value = "studentID"`

then it leaves A1 empty, but B1 works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Inside the excel application go to the developer tab on the ribbon and click record macro.
2. Type the values into the two cells manually.
3. Click stop recording and view the macro it created.

This would show you VBA code that will work and you can compare it to what you have in order to trouble shoot.

This is called recording a macro and can be very helpful in solving problems. In fact I would suggest doing so almost every time before asking a question here.

Comment: I just edited it.  My point was to help him learn how to find problems in his code.

Comment: Here is what I got and what works when I paste it in my code:
`    Range("A1").Select  
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "studentID"   
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ISUID"`

and I think I'll just go with it. Thank you for the answer! I will sure use this technique in the future :)